# Can't see any projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to use `Set up deployment from source control` to allow publishing from my TFS project to Azure, but for some reason after I authorize, it says I have no projects. The accounts are correct, I was just wondering, is there some kind of criteria for it to allow the integration or something?

I get this window

[image]

Yet I have two projects on my TFS Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up closing my azure account and getting off of team foundation service, that solved the problem.